# does other Directory Services than Active Directory have a unique identifier for each object in the directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

At active directory, each AD object has an objectGUID attribute which uniquely identifies the AD object even after it is renamed or moved, see link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. Do we have such concept in other LDAP directory services such as (Novell Directory Service)? I did some search on on internet and could not find any confirmation on this. I did see this RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4530, Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) entryUUID Operational Attribute, however not sure how wide it is implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute '`GUID`' is present in Novell Directory begining in NetWare 5.x ([see this documentation](http://developer.novell.com/documentation/ndslib/pdfdoc/schm_enu/schm_enu.pdf)). So you can find it in Novell Directory Service. '`entryUUID`' is present  in SUN (Oracle) ePlanet, OpenLdap and OpenDS.

In my understanding such an attribute is present as an *operational attribute* in each Directory server whatever the editor is. This attribute is used in replication processes to synchronize objects between servers. The problem I met is that in some case (ActiveDirectory) its internal syntax is '*binary*', in other case openLDAP its internal syntax is '*Directory String*'.

Be careful of the fact that, this is an **OPERATIONAL** attribut, that means that **it CAN'T be modified using LDAP**. People coming from openLDAP usualy use '*slapxxx*' operation to fill the database, it's not LDAP operation, and this kind of usage is not allowed in all Directory servers.

Answer (score 3):

`entryUUID` is implemented by all directory servers that that purport to support the LDAP standards framework. The words `SHALL` and `MUST` in the RFC (4530) are clear indicators that the attribute must be supported.

Answer (score 2):

entryUUID is supported in both ApacheDS and OpenLDAP (and yes it is equivalent of GUID)